# Window to stay on top if desktop is shown, but not on top of other windows (Qt)

Tags: qt, pyqt

I am writing a little application with PyQt4.

With "WindowStaysOnTopHint" I can make the window of the app stay on top of other windows. Now I want to click on the bottom right button of Windows7 which shows the desktop, minimizing everything. But the programm (a note app) should stay always visible and not being minimized.

With the "WindowStaysOnTopHint" it works, but it also stays on top of every other window, e.g. firefox, which is not what I want.

Is there a special command for it or can I filter somehow for the "show desktop"-button?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the eventFilter() method such that if the user focuses out, (clicks on something else outside the window), you can disable the stays on stop flag.

```
class MyWidget(QWebView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()
        self.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, qobject, qevent):
        qtype = qevent.type()
        if qtype == QEvent.FocusOut:
           #disable the stay on top flag, by setting some other flag
           self.setWindowFlags(WindowCloseButtonHint)
           return True
        return super(MyWidget, self).eventFilter(qobject, qevent)
```